# Setting fill style of flex legend item not working

Tags: apache-flex, legend

I have been trying (but to no avail) to set the background color of a legend item in Flex to a color of my choosing.

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working.

I obtain a reference to the legendItem in question and then set the fill style like so:

```
var legendItem:LegendItem = event.item;
var legendItemColor:SolidColor = new SolidColor(0x00FF00, 0.5);
legendItem.setStyle("fill", legendItemColor);
```

I am able to set other styles of the legend item but, for some reason, this isn't working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the effect I was looking for by setting the opaqueBackground property of the legendItem.

```
legendItem.opaqueBackground = 0x00FF00;
```

Doesn't really make sense and I had even found an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flex/Chart/CreateacustomlegendinActionScript.htm) where setStyle of fill was used and seemed to work for them.

Oh well, as long as it works!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2008/07/customized_legend_layout.html

Comment: Yes, it's basically the same example as in the link I posted above.  Strange that it won't work.  Thanks for posting though.